# How to make a Vue plugin function call methods on the related component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins

I'd like to make a Vue plugin that registers a global component and allows the plugin methods (accessible globally via `this.$magic`). For example:

#### src/plugins/magic.js

```
import Magic from './Magic.vue';

export default {
  install(VueInstance) {
    console.log('Installing');

    VueInstance.component('magic', Magic);
    VueInstance.prototype.$magic = {
      increment() {
        // ???
      },
    };
  },
};
```

And in the `Magic.vue` component, there's a method that should be called when a developer invokes `this.$magic.increment()`. I'm not sure how to do this, and the Vue documentation doesn't really get into these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for staters, writing "VueInstance" is false because, it's the Vue class function that is handed to you, not an instance of Vue.

Now to answer you question, which is not totally clear for me, I would say you need to use a state management system.

If I understand well, you want to create on the Vue prototype, a method that calls another method part of each instance of your component "Magic".
(Why do I say each instance? Because you cannont call a method from your Component's definition, you must instance it to access one of it's methods or data).

To be honest, this seems too complicated but since I don't know what your final goal is, here are some clues:

1. You could create an empty instance of your component to access it's methods.

```
Import Magic from './Magic.vue';

const myMagic = new (Vue.extend(Magic));

export default {
  install(VueInstance) {
    console.log('Installing');

    VueInstance.component('magic', Magic);
    VueInstance.prototype.$magic = {
      increment() {
        myMagic.method()
      }
    };
  }
};
```

In theory, all instances of your Magic component will have the same method, so this works but, this won't change the state of all your instances, here you just have access to the method (so I don't see the use case, a service/utility would be better, see #2)

2. Use a shared state and a shared method that your Magic component imports instead of trying to use a method from your Magic component.

Shared.js

```
export const state = {
  somedata: 0
};

export const methods = {
  inc() {
    state.somedata++
  }
};
```

Magic.vue

```
import { state, methods}  from './Shared.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      shared: state
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Something () {
      methods.inc();
    }
  }
};
```

Plugin.js

```
import { state, methods}  from './Shared.js'
import Magic from './Magic.vue';

export default {
  install(VueInstance) {
    console.log('Installing');

    VueInstance.component('magic', Magic);
    VueInstance.prototype.$magic = {
      increment() {
        methods.inc()
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Globally here, you could just share it in this way (and it's reactive because a gave the object reference to the Magic component data which will be the sae reference for each instance, so shared).

3. Do #2 but using vuex with state and mutations or actions.

Final note, since we don't know what you are trying to do in your component's method it's hard to be helpful. Please try to detail more if one of the following answers does not solve your use case.